# ORACLE - Get the last record for each hour

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, greatest-n-per-group

i have a datetime field, which sometimes it's retrieving me duplicate data, I need one record per hour, for that if the same objectid has 3 records at the same hour example 11 PM I need to take the last record from that hour
example
record 1 11:05 pm
record 2 11:35 pm
record 3 11:55 pm

pick only the record from 11:55 pm, the last record of each hour, could be that objectid has more records in different hours but I need just one record per hour picking the last one with more minutes. anY IDEA?
if i use max value would get just one record per objectid, i need one per hour the last one.

```sql
select *
from   prod.WX_RAW
where  trunc(datetimeutc,'DD') = to_date('01-01-2021')
and    objectid=10000355399 
and    TEMP_CODE NOT IN ('7','2','3','R','U')
and    OBS_TYPEID IN ('7', '4', '6')
and    REPORTTYPE = 'FM-15'
ORDER BY DATETIMEUTc;
```

example data:

```
object id.  datetimeutc                     obstype country code.   wind direction
10000355399 1/1/2021 11:15:00.000000000 PM  7       KCLK    V020    340  N
10000355399 1/1/2021 11:35:00.000000000 PM  7       KCLK    V020    350  N
10000355399 1/1/2021 11:55:00.000000000 PM  7       KCLK    V020    360  N
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  select w.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY objectid, TRUNC(datetimeutc, 'HH')
           ORDER BY datetimeutc DESC
         ) AS rn
  from   prod.WX_RAW w
  where  trunc(datetimeutc,'DD') = DATE '2021-01-01'
  and    objectid=10000355399 
  and    TEMP_CODE NOT IN ('7','2','3','R','U')
  and    OBS_TYPEID IN ('7', '4', '6')
  and    REPORTTYPE = 'FM-15'
)
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY DATETIMEUTc;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2becbc25c003d10521a93d1b3ba35b3c)*

Comment: Hi, I have 40 diffenrent objectids where trunc(datetimeutc,'dd') BETWEEN to_date ('01-01-2021') AND TO_DATE('01-02-2021') BUT your code just return one objectid, it does return the last record of each hour and tha's good but doesnt show me the others (I deleted the filter objectid= 10000355399)

Comment: @Webb The question just says "I need one record per hour" and does not make it clear that you want "one record per hour per objectid" .... just add `objectid` to the partition clause.